# Website not returning cookies

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I am trying to log into a website to send SMS via a windows phone 7 app. I have 2 providers working but when I try Vodafone I am running into an error.

From what I gather it seems that the response does not contain cookies, or they are not being read. The request logs in ok and the response I get back is the correct page but it contains no cookies.

The Url:

```
RequestUrl = String.Format("https://www.vodafone.ie/myv/services/login/Login.shtml?username={0}&password={1}", userSettings.Username, userSettings.Password),
```

The Request:

```
     Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create((requestCollection.CurrentRequest().RequestUrl));

        if (Request.CookieContainer == null)
        {
            Request.CookieContainer = cookieJar.CookieContainer;
            Request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            Request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
            Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.6) Gecko/20060728 Firefox/1.5.0.6";
        }
```

Where the code errors as the response cookies could not be evaluated:

```
    public void AddCookiesToContainer(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
         CookieCollection.Add(response.Cookies);
         CookieContainer.Add(response.ResponseUri, CookieCollection);
    }
```

And below is the debugger showing no cookies :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nobody have any suggestions ? :(

Comment: CookieCollection = new CookieCollection();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which line of the code has the error?

Have you verified that the service does return cookies? (i.e. If you make the same request from a PC)

Edit:
The remote host is returning cookies in it's redirection to the index page but in that page there are no cookies in the response. This would explain why there are no cookies in the collection when you try and use it.

Verify this behaviour against a PC client, inspect the body of the response from index.jsp ans this may contain information to help debug and check the documentation on how the process is supposed to work.

Comment: I presume it does as I would have no other way to continue with my process. It fails at the add cookies to request. It gives an null refrence exception and the output is shown above. Added Fiddler Screenshots.

Comment: Let me know if they are not the right screens I am new to fiddler2.

Comment: In the intial response there is this line: Set-cookie: supercookie=-; expires=Thursday, 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00 GMT; path=/. But in the redirect there is no cookie that I can see.

Comment: Sorted:             CookieCollection = new CookieCollection();